# Appropriate response to an email: electronic communications etiquette

Tags: email, conventions

Considering the following email message:

```
Cher Matthew,

Merci pour ces documents et pour vos explications sur votre parcours,
atypique mais intéressant. 
Comme vous l'avez surement noté dans l'annonce, 
les candidatures sont ouvertes jusqu'au 30 juin. 
Nous prendrons en principe notre décision au cours de la premiere quinzaine de juillet.

Bien cordialement,

Jean-Philippe
```

I know that in different cultures there are different acceptable norms of conversation. For instance, in the United States it's considered rude to begin a correspondence without some preliminary pleasantries known as "small talk".

In French language, in French culture what would be an appropriate reply to a mail like the one specified above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say first ;

***Je vous remercie beaucoup pour l'intérêt que vous avez porté à ma candidature***

This kind of sentence could be a good preliminary sentence. After this sentence, you can ask your question (if you have some).

Comment: Then you could add `Dans l'attente de votre décision, je me tiens à votre entière disposition si vous avez besoin d'information supplémentaires.`. And end by as he did `Cordialement`.

Comment: Of course, adding an "s" at the end of "information" would probably be a good idea.